# Незавершеные транзакции в InnoDB - переносимость кода

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

Пример транзакции (словами, без кода):

```
1 считать строку из тбл ожидания регистрации

2 записать в тбл юзерс одну строку

3 записать в тбл опции настройки пользователя
```

Сейчас у меня код рассчитан для\на MyISAM. После каждого шага (1 2 3) происходит проверка результата выполнения. Если ошибка, то вызвать функцию er($x); , которая сообщит что "все пропало" и exit;

А если код будет работать с InnoDB (если обозначить начало\конец транзакции), то что будет с таблицами (со строками) на которых (при работе с которыми) возникли ошибки и вызвалась функция er($x); ?

Получится ли это мертвая транзакция? Сам не очень понимаю что значит "мертвая транзакция".

Answer (score 1):

Да, вам так же будут возвращаться сообщения об ошибках, однако, перед `exit()` вы будете выполнять еще один запрос `ROLLBACK` - который сообщит серверу, что транзакция не может быть завершена успешно и все изменения в рамках транзакций просто не будут записаны в вашу базу данных. В результате база данных будет в том же состоянии, что и до начала транзакции.

Если же вы успешно добрались до последнего запроса, вы отправляете `COMMIT`, получив который, СУБД запишет изменения в затронутые таблицы.

Comment: Уже понятнее, а ничего страшного не будет если **rollback писать в функц обработки ошибок**, перед exit;? Ну это еще предстоит на практике посмотреть\поглядеть.

Comment: Как правильно называется такое состояние бд, транзакции? Только не говорите что  оно называется "мертвая транзакция".

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy rollback как раз стоит написать в функции обработки ошибок. получаете текущий номер/текст ошибки БД, даете rollback, выдаете сообщение пользователю. Я сам не представляю, что такое "мертвая транзакция". Транзакция может быть завершенной, когда данные уже в БД и "не завершенной", пока они еще в БД не отражены, других состояний быть не может. Откаченные транзакции просто не считаются. P.S.  не забудьте при установке соединения с базой выключить автоматический commit после каждой операции (который часто по умолчанию)

Comment: привет Mike ;) Об автоматическом комите не знал. У меня из этого вопроса (этих ответов) выплыл еще один вопрос: о rollback без begin. Задам его чуть позже.